# Allow commands to run after backgrounding django runserver command in a bash script?

Tags: python, django, bash, backgrounding

I'm writing a 'simple' script to start up the django server, background it then start up firefox while I dev.

I've seen the [`</dev/null &`](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4996#trac-change-9-1288057753000000) trick and that works on the command line. But when I use it in my script it still hangs on the server starting. Backgrounding with <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> and the `bg` command only backgrounds the script and not the command.

Is there a way I can pass django a 'Don't hog input' flag? Or I can background it inside the script in some way other than putting `&` at the end of it? Or just tell the script not to run it all in a separate session?

Here's my script in full (it's full on hard-core ugly, it might get prettified if I can get this to work):

```
SETTING_ENV=$1
if [ "$PWD" = "/home/$USERNAME/PROJECT/" ]; then
    pid=$(for pid in $(pidof -x "python"); do ps -p $pid -o pid,cmd --no-heading; done| grep [m]anage|head -1|cut -d" " -f2)
    if [ -z $pid ]; then
        python ./manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.$SETTING_ENV < /dev/null &
    else
        echo "Server still running on : $pid"
    fi
    pids=$(pidof -x firefox)
    for pid in $pids; do
        echo $pid
        if [ -z $pid ]; then
             echo "starting firefox"
             firefox --new-window localhost:8000 &
        else ecjp "Firefox already running on pid: $pid"
        fi
    done
else
    echo "$PWD is not /home/$USERNAME/PROJECT";
fi
```

Comment: Can I just check these updates are from people with a similar problem? This sounds like it should have a simple solution - no lots of upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your command in parenthesis like this :

```
(python ./manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.$SETTING_ENV < /dev/null &)
```

When you run a command between parentheses it will create a new sub-shell so when you will quit the shell the command will continues to run.

Or you can also use disown or nohup :

```
python ./manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.$SETTING_ENV < /dev/null & 
disown
```

-

```
nohup python ./manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.$SETTING_ENV < /dev/null &
```

Comment: Neither of these (in this example) pass control back to the script. I've used all three methods you've mentioned elsewhere I an know they *normally* work. In the `disown` case when I killed the process for `./manage runserver` is output: `./start_gui.sh: line 21: 4932 Terminated          python ./manage.py runderver --settings=project.settings.$SETTING_ENV < /dev/null`